# Styles changed suddenly on api-details

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a managed instance of developer portal, suddenly elemets like the tag, code section on try it and are a mess:

[image]

I cannot even click on the Copy button of the code block.

Any ideas what could it be? I have checked the styles section on the editor and everything looks fine. Is there a way to reset the styles only?

Answer (score 0):

After checking around I found a misplaced height in the menu:

[image]